# Wait until data (30,000 rows) is displayed after AJAX request before calling function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically I have a function that cannot be called until it's data has been processed.

My `data.done` function apparently did not work, there is about 30,000 + records so therefore the browser lags for about 5 seconds, and the function is called before the data has been processed meaning the function will not work.

`$('#order').html(data)` is the culprit, and I need to find a way to know when it has finished processing the data?

I really hope you guys/gals can help me on this one.

```html
<script>
  function DataTable() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
      responsive: true
    });
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loading").show();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
    DataTable()
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text').text('');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      url: "vieworderhistory",
      timeout: 120000,
      cache: true,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#order').html(data).done(function() {
          alert("Data processed.");
          DataTable() //This is the function I want to be called when the data has been processed and is on the browser page.
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly `html()` is a synchronous function which is why calling `done()` on it will throw an error. However the issue is moot as you should definitely not be dumping 30,000 records in to the DOM. Use filtering, paging and searching to reduce the result set to a useable size to be shown in the UI

Comment: cant you just do $('#order').html(data); alert('done'); ? success function is pretty much request done, response received

Comment: and yeah, 1st guy's comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#order').html(data);
alert("Data processed.");
DataTable();
```

This should work. The alert will show up only when `$('#order').html(data)` will be done.